# Unable to run TestNG classes in sequential order

Tags: java, c#, testng

I want my testng to run my classes in Sequential mode. I have mentioned  `suite name="WebData-Sanity"` `parallel="false"` `thread-count="1"` in my `testng.xml`, Still its running parallel. All the test classes are starting at a time. How ever If I am putting individual classes in individual `<test>` its running sequential.

```xml
<suite name="WebData-Sanity" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
    <test name="WebData-Sanity" preserve-order="`enter code here`true" parallel="false"
        thread-count="1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Sanity" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="flipKartTest.FlipKartFirstPageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Regression">
        <classes>
            <class name="flipKartTest.FlipKartHomePageTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want all my classes in Same `<tests>` tag

Comment: Code Snippet - <suite name="WebData-Sanity" parallel="false" thread-count="1">
 <test name="WebData-Sanity" preserve-order="`enter code here`true" parallel="false"
  thread-count="1">
  <groups>
   <run>
    <include name="Sanity" />
   </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
   <class name="flipKartTest.FlipKartFirstPageTest" />
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="Regression">
  <classes>
   <class name="flipKartTest.FlipKartHomePageTest" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

I want all my classes in Same <tests> tag

Comment: If you want to add code to your question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57483887/edit) it and add it there.

Comment: @aptro044 you can learn asking the question from this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @aptro044 How are you saying that its running in parallel? Have you tried printing the thread IDs using `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());` and seeing different values for each of your classes ?

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan- To check your comment I created 2 classes TestNGClassB- which contains MethodA and methodB to print A and B, priority given to them as 1 and 2 resp. Another Class TestNGClassA- contains MethodC and MethodD to print C and D, priority for them is 1 & 2.  TestNG.xml suite parallel=none class order is TestNGClassB and TestNGClassA, Expected o/p - A B C D, But getting A C B D and syso(Thread.currentThread().getId()) gives 1 as o/p in all the cases. TestNG tried - 6.11, 6.14.3, Both the case same result. Any suggestions?